# How to install Canon Pixma MG3600?

Tags: canon, pixma

How do I install the driver for a Canon Pixma MG3600 on Ubuntu 32-bit?

Answer (score 5):

To install the drivers:

1. Get the drivers [here](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/2/0100006902/01/cnijfilter2-5.20-1-deb.tar.gz):

   - [source](http://www.canon-printerdrivers.com/2015/12/canon-pixma-mg3600-driver-download-mac.html)
2. Extract file from terminal in the download directory:

   ```
   tar -zxvf cnijfilter2-5.20-1-deb.tar.gz
   ```

   - extract by right clicking with mouse and selecting *extract here*
3. Change into the extracted directory *(cnijfilter2-5.20-1-deb)* and run:

   ```
   ./install.sh
   ```

With that your drivers are ready to use.

Comment: thanks, only thing I noticed about this printer/scanner is that the connection has to be direct wifi as going via my ISP router I am permanently having to perform the setup with my android phone.